# Subtract one second from a given time

Tags: php, datetime, time

I would like to add 1 day and then subtract ( minus ) 1 second from a given time.

I did:

```
$fromDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2012-09-28")).' 00:00:00';
$date = strtotime(date("y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime($fromDate)) . " +1 day") - 1;
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', $date);
echo $toDate;
```

but instead of `2012-09-28 23:59:59` it returns `2012-09-29 00:09:59`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: problem is at your date format, part "H:m:s"... you are printing "hour month seconds"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're going round and round instead of getting to the point in your code. Here's my solution with `DateTime` objects:

```
$time = new DateTime("2012-09-28");
$time->modify("+1 day");
$time->modify("-1 second");

var_dump($time);
```

Or, if you just need the last second of the day, why not just:

```
$time = "2012-09-28";
$time .= " 23:59:59";
```

As it's unlikely that the number of seconds/minutes/hours a day to change.

Comment: The modify function doesn't change the object. Just returns a new DateTime object with the modified time.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, you just want the last second in the given day, right?

If that's the case, then you could just have:

```
$theDate = "2012-09-28";
$fromDate = $theDate." 00:00:00";
$toDate = $theDate." 23:59:59";
```